# Showing Dialog when Home Screen Causing Gray Screen

Tags: android

I have asynctask running, when finish, I dismiss the progressDialog and call AlertDialog accordingly:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setMessage("Test")
    .setCancelable(false)
    .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

    }
});
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();
```

**Standy on app**

> 1. Standby on app
> 2. Asynctask on going
> 3. Asynctask is finished, progressDialog is dismissed
> 4. (Still standby on app) AlertDialog appears as it should be

**Home screen**

> 1. Asynctask on going
> 2. Go to home screen
> 3. Asynctask is finished, progressDialog is dismissed
> 4. AlertDialog is called to show
> 5. Goes back to app, but alertdialog doesn't appear, it gives me greyed screen instead.

Is there any way to solve this? I tried to search it but couldn't find someone has same issue..

Comment: Could you edit your question to included the exact process your going through to get the greyed screen.

Comment: I edited my question, hope it clearer now..

Comment: Are you wanting your AlertDialog to appear while your app is not foreground or simply be displayed when your app is returned to foreground?

Comment: Hmm actually what I can expect is, the dialog appears not matter when I am on foreground or background. Surely, I can add some logic to make it appear when onResume but I think I can expect the dialog should be shown too when I am on background, don't I?

Answer (score 1):

Ok. (As from your comments).

You can not have your dialog automatically appear while your app is in the background. The dialog is displayed within the context of your Activity(along with its window manager), if the activity is not displayed, nor is your dialog.

To display content while your activity is in the background you have a few options, non of which will be straight forward though.

1. Attach views directly to Android's `WindowManager`. This will not work with a dialog, you would have to construct a dialog layout and manually attach it, it would remain foreground above everything else.
2. Launch your dialog from a transparent activity. Problem here is if you are say on your homescreen then the transparent activity/dialog launches and you then call you application the transparent activity/dialog will be dismissed into the background.
3. Launch an activity with a dialog theme. This "may" work as needed, if you call your main application keeping the stack correct. Would have to test to be sure.

Comment: So I assume that there is no "easy" way to do it? I think I want to redesign my app again :D Thanks Jug6ernaut!

Comment: No easy way without changing what your trying to do no. The problem here is your trying to go against how Android UI life cycle works. (when you press the home button, its supposed to go home). It can be done, but it will take some ugly spaghetti code.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Android Design Guide you should show a Notification instead of the AlertDialog when your AsyncTask has finished and the Activity is in background (paused). To decide what you should show, maintain a boolean variable in your Activity. Set the variable to true in`Activity.onResume()` and false in `Activity.onPaused()`.

Basically you implement `onPostExecute` in your `AsyncTask`. In there you make the ProgressBar invisible and show the Alert Dialog with the code you show in your question.

More about `AsyncTask` is [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

More about `Notifications` is [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html)

The [Design Guide in question](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) is here. Scroll down to 'Sending Notifications to the User'. Essentially, what you do with the AsyncTask in background is like running a Service. At least from the user experience standpoint. Differences between your approach and a Service are internal, e.g. Android will kill your process when it needs space differently.

Comment: Hmm can you provide me the link of the guide? I seem only can find this information: "Ongoing notifications keep users informed about an ongoing process in the background."

Comment: @Rendy. Just recognized that I mispelled your name. In the meantime I added a link with the guide to my answer.